# Can the mouseover event be used on any element, or only on images?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

```
<html >
 <head>   
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function greet { 
        var greet = document.getElementById("greeting");
        greet.value="this is dynamic";
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p onmouseover="greet()"> Hello! Welcome to My Page </p> 
</html>
```

What is the problem in this code?

Comment: isn't it supposed to be " greet.innerHTML = "sometext" "? Also, make sure that there is a tag in your HTML file that has an ID of greeting, like: <div id="greeting">Hello! Welcome!</div>

Comment: Exactly: What is the problem? Please elaborate on the problem you encounter. What does it (not) do? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you haven't closed your `greet` function (missing the closing `}` character). Secondly, you're missing the parentheses after the name of the function:

```
function greet() {
    //Function body
}
```

Secondly, you're using `getElementById` to try and obtain a reference to the `p` element, but the `p` element doesn't have an `id`.

Thirdly, the `greet` variable will contain a reference to a `p` element, which doesn't have a `value` property (like, for example, `input` elements do). You may have meant `innerHTML` if you are trying to change the contents of the element.

Finally, you haven't closed your `<body>` element. *Edit (see comments)* - This isn't a problem, but personally I prefer closing it for consistency.

You could pass a reference to the element into the function when it's called, to save you having to get it by `id`:

```
<p onmouseover="greet(this);">Example</p>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function greet(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = "Something new";
}
```

Comment: The end tag for the body element is optional.

Comment: You can also leave out the start tag if it is consistency you are looking for >:)

Comment: Yeah again true, but it's just my personal style to always include both start tag and end tag :)

Answer (score 0):

the p element should have an ID of greet, as in:

```
<p onmouseover="greet()" id="greeting"> Hello! Welcome to My Page </p>
```

, so that when you select the element's ID at:

```
document.getElementById("greeting");
```

the document can find the tag you are trying to select from the HTML document.

Additionally, instead of editing the node's "value" attribute, I think you need to use the "innerHTML" instead. So that gives:

```
<html >
 <head>   
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function greet { 
        var greet = document.getElementById("greeting");
        greet.innerHTML="this is dynamic";
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 </body>
   <p onmouseover="greet()" id="greeting"> Hello! Welcome to My Page </p> 
</html>
```

I am not exactly familiar with JavaScript, but I believe that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
greet = function(elem) {
             elem.innerHTML = "Something new";
        }
```

or

```
greet = function() {
            var greet = document.getElementById("greeting");
            greet.innerHTML="this is dynamic";
        }
```

Along with the other tips of course(like `id` attribute for the relevant `<p>` element and well-forming your HTML).